# Captcha Recognition using CNN not giving expected results

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, convolution, conv-neural-network

I tried to develop a Captcha Recognition program using TensorFlow in Python.

When I started, I checked some articles on the internet and found that a Captcha image is segmented into individual digits and these individual digits are recognized. But I wanted to try a different approach. I wanted to recognize Captcha without segmentation.

**References :**

[Automatic Number Plate Recognition](https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/) - I used this blog post as a reference.

[Code for ANPR](https://github.com/matthewearl/deep-anpr) - This is the code from the above blog post.

**My Solution :**

[Code for my Solution](https://github.com/karthik512/Captcha-Recognition)

**Generating Data :**

I generated around 60000 160 * 60 RGB images. All the captchas were of length 6. I used 25000 images as training data and 9000 images as test data and did not use the rest of the images.

**Sample Data :**

[image: 0A6ZYC]  ----> 0A6ZYC

[image: 0A9L8W]  ----> 0A9L8W

[image: 0AKDTP]  ----> 0AKDTP

**Neural Network Architecture :**

160 * 60 * 3 ------(5*5 Conv)---> 160*60*24 ------(2*2 MaxPool)--->80*30*24 ----(5*5 Conv) ----> 80*30*36 ----(4*2 MaxPool)----> 20*15*36 ----(Fully Connected)--->(4096*1) -----(Fully Connected)--->(216*1)

**Some other properties of the Network :**

1) Mini Batch Size : 100

2) Optimizer : Adam Optimizer

3) Epochs : 60

4) Captcha Length : 6

6) Characters Used : [A-Z0-9]

**Problems Faced:**

1) When I had one more Convolution Layer, my network started to output the same value. I tried Normalization but there was no change. So I removed the layer and changed the final Maxpool layer from (2*2) to (4*2). I had run the program for 30 epochs

2) Now, when I run the program for 60 epochs with the above architecture I get around 50% accuracy on my training set after 50 or 55 epochs but I get 0-5% accuracy on my test set.

What am I missing in this network? Is it the data that is wrong? Is my approach correct? Why am I not getting good results?